# How to select all form elements?

Tags: jquery

I usually just do this:

```
   $("#formid input, #formid select, #formid textarea")
```

But is there any shorthand for this, like..

```
   $("#formid All-Form-Elements")
```

?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind, though it's barely short hand (and not really an answer), is $("#formid").find("input, select, textarea").

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You seem to be looking for the [:input](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector:

```
var formElements = $("#formid :input");
```

Note that it also matches `<button>` elements.

Comment: this grabs all of them, even selects, textarea, checkbox and radio?

Comment: Yes, it matches all types of `<input>` elements, plus `<select>`, `<textarea>` and `<button>` elements.

Comment: Works great, thank you.. do you know how to set a checkbox selected without using attr('checked','checked'); ?

Comment: I've personally been using `prop("checked", true)` since jQuery 1.6.

Comment: If you're in one of the many situations where jQuery sets `this` to be the DOM element, you can simply say `this.checked=true;`.

Answer (score 7):

Use the **[`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)** selector, which selects all `<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>` and `<button>` elements.

```
$("#formid :input")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get all the form element, including: **input, textarea, select**

```
var paramString ='';
$('#formID').find('input, textarea, select').each(function(){
   paramString += '&' + $(this).attr('name') + '=' + ($(this).val();
});
```

I hope this will save someone's time :)